# Autolinker for multiple elements by a classname

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I managed to implement the autolinker script on my website by use of this code example, available at the Autolinker.js [documentation](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autolinker/1.4.3/Autolinker.min.js">
```

```
var myTextEl = document.getElementById( 'description' );
myTextEl.innerHTML = Autolinker.link( myTextEl.innerHTML );
```

#### What I want

Now, however, I want to use the script in multiple locations on the same page. 
The classname is `.description`
The linked documentation in this matter either is unclear or above my js skills. Please help me with this issue.

If possible, I'd prefer to use the 3.0 version of the script. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll('.description')
descriptions.forEach(x => {
  x.innerHTML = Autolinker.link(x.innerHTML)
})
```